# Angularjs - Using Typeahead have to show 2 values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `typeahead`, I like it to fetch dynamic data it's more useful

```
 <input required type="text" ng-model="student" 
  placeholder="{{'STUDENT_ID_FIRST_NAME_LAST_NAME' | translate}}" 
  typeahead="student as student.lastName for student in getStudents($viewValue)"
  typeahead-loading="loading" class="form-control">
```

My javascript code to fetch students is

```
$scope.getStudents = function(val) {
    var queryCriteria = {
        q: JSON.stringify([{
            field: 'lastName',
            op: APP_CONSTANTS.SEARCH_OPERATORS.CONTAINS,
            value: val
        }, {
            field: 'firstName',
            op: APP_CONSTANTS.SEARCH_OPERATORS.CONTAINS,
            value: val
        }, {
            field: 'userId',
            op: APP_CONSTANTS.SEARCH_OPERATORS.CONTAINS,
            value: val
        }]),
        joinCondition: APP_CONSTANTS.JOIN_CONDITIONS.OR,
        order: APP_CONSTANTS.SORTING_ORDER.DESCENDING,
        limit: 10,
        orderBy: 'createdAt',
        page: 1
    }
    return Students.query(queryCriteria).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

I want to show concatenation of `student.lastName` and `student.firstName`. Please suggest how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do use string concatenation `student.lastName + ' ' + student.firstName`

```
<input required type="text" ng-model="student" 
placeholder="{{'STUDENT_ID_FIRST_NAME_LAST_NAME' | translate}}" 
typeahead="student as student.lastName+' '+student.firstName for student in getStudents($viewValue)" 
typeahead-loading="loading" class="form-control">
```

Comment: It's working fine pankajparkar. Thanks. And I didn't think html will accept like javascript. And it's beauty of typeahead/angularjs

Comment: @Veerabhadra its angularjs magic..It evaluates expression very elegantly on UI :)